# WITH AS in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

What if I have different tables on my oracle query, how can I group them in one `WITH AS` query:

```
WITH A AS (
                SELECT A,B FROM TABLE1,
                SELECT C FROM TABLE2 ---> ??
     )
```

I want to translate my query with "with as" function including different tables. but it seems selecting another column form other table is not working.

```
Table1
A             B
data1        data1



Table2 
C
Data1
```

i just want to query them into one "With AS" statement. :)

output should be

```
A            B          C
data1       data1     data1
```

Comment: Are you trying to get columns from two different tables? The rules for that are the same as for a normal query across two tables. The with clause won't make a difference.

Comment: it this case it should be fine if I inner joins the two tables?

Answer (score 2):

There is no obvious reason why you need to use sub-query factoring but here is how to do it:

```
with data as ( select table1.A, table1.B, table2.C
               from table1 cross join table2 )
select * from data;
```

Obviously as your question doesn't provide any join criteria a cartesian product is the result you can have.  I suspect that isn't what you want but unless you most sufficient details who can tell?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT A, B  FROM TABLE1
    UNION/UNION ALL
    SELECT '','',C FROM TABLE2
)
```